# Reset other branch to current without a checkout

Tags: git

I'm writing some scripts for my Git workflow.

I need to reset other (existing) branch to the current one, without checkout.

Before:

```
 CurrentBranch: commit A
 OtherBranch: commit B
```

After:

```
 CurrentBranch: commit A
 OtherBranch: commit A
```

Equivalent of

```
 $ git checkout otherbranch 
 $ git reset --soft currentbranch
 $ git checkout currentbranch
```

(Note `--soft`: I do not want to affect working tree.)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The workflows you describe are not equivalent: when you perform `reset --hard` you lose all the changes in the working tree (you might want to make it `reset --soft`).

What you need is

```
git update-ref refs/heads/OtherBranch refs/heads/CurrentBranch
```

Comment: Man, I wish this worked without the superfluous `refs/heads/` …

Comment: A much nicer way to do this is `git push . current:other`. This works without `refs/heads` (/cc @elliottcable), and it also prevents you from updating the checked-out branch. Note that you may need to pass -f (or use `+current:other`) if the update isn't a fast-forward.

Comment: You can also use `-m 'some text'` argument to record the reason for the ref update to be shown by `git reflog OtherBranch` command, such as "synched to CurrentBranch". May be useful to remember why you did it later.

Comment: Why would you use `git update-ref refs/heads/OtherBranch refs/heads/CurrentBranch` or `git push . CurrentBranch OtherBranch` when you could use the much cleaner (IMO) `git branch -f OtherBranch CurrentBranch` instead?  (See [my answer on git branch -f](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17604903/994153) below)

Comment: @BenHymers So the man page for "git push" is a damn lie. It describes the command as "Update remote refs ...". when in fact it can update local refs just fine.

Comment: @ColinDBennett to save future readers some time: `git branch -f` won't work if OtherBranch is currently checked out, whereas `git update-ref` will.

Answer (score 344):

Set `otherbranch` to point at the same commit as `currentbranch` by running

```
git branch -f otherbranch currentbranch
```

The `-f` (force) option tells `git branch` *yes, I really mean to overwrite any existing `otherbranch` reference with the new one*.

From the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

> -f
>   --force
>
> Reset  to  if  exists already. Without -f git branch refuses to change an existing branch.

Comment: I get `fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.` when trying to do this.

Comment: @FuadSaud that's because you already have `otherbranch` checked out.  This SO question is specifically about resetting *another* branch to a different commit (i.e. not resetting the checked-out branch).  What you want to do is reset the current branch with `git reset targetbranch` to force the current branch to be pointed at `targetbranch`.   Add `--hard` to also force the work tree to that content.  Or `--soft` to leave the index alone and only change the branch itself.

Comment: Right, so, I know about reset. What I was looking for was a way to, inside a routine, always point local master to upstream/master, independently of what's checked out. I thought `branch -f` could do that.

Comment: @FuadSaud You could use `git checkout -B master upstream/master` which would work regardless of whether master is checked out locally.  But it will also switch the branch to master. If you have local changes in the workspace, probably bad.

Comment: It actually fits with Git's model that you use a different command for *simply moving a branch pointer* as `git branch -f` will do versus updating the current branch including workspace, which is what `git reset` and `git checkout` do, since it's not allows to modify the checked out branch.  Note that Git won't let you push to a remote's currently checked-out branch.

Comment: @FuadSaud so it seems that the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1591255/1026) of `git update-ref refs/heads/OtherBranch refs/heads/CurrentBranch` is what we're looking for.

Comment: `git branch -f <branchname> <start-point>` works fine with remote refs so long as you provide the full ref name as `git branch -f master refs/remotes/origin/master`

Comment: The problem with this is, that it destroys the upstream branch info etc. of `otherbranch`. So the `git update-ref` method is more clean, but tedious to type. But one could use an alias or script.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to fast-forward a (local) branch to my checked-out branch without first switching, and I always searched for it, fruitlessly, in those terms. Finally it occurred to me to think of it as resetting the other branch, and searching for it that way led straight to this answer. Love it! If you just want to reset `otherbranch` to the current checkout, `currentbranch` can be omitted.

Answer (score 28):

You can sync with this command your branches at any time

```
$ git push . CurrentBranch:OtherBranch -f
```

Also without -f it replace this set of commands

```
$ git checkout OtherBranch
$ git merge CurrentBranch
$ git checkout CurrentBranch
```

It can be useful when you don't need commit all your files in CurrentBranch and so you can't switch to another branches.

Comment: May cause "remote: error: denying non-fast-forward"

Comment: I wouldn't include `-f` option unless it’s absolutely inevitable. It works well without it in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good but a little scary.  I'm just providing another option to achieve exactly what was asked for somewhat simply with variations on commands I use every day.

In short, None of these options mess with the current branch you're on or current head.

`git branch -C other_branch` (force-create other_branch from current HEAD)

To reset other_branch to a branch you're not on...

`git branch -C old_branch other_branch` (force-create other_branch from old_branch)

To reset other_branch to some_branch on the remote, it's a little bit different...

`git pull -f origin old_branch:other_branch` (force-pull (which ignores the already-up-to-date stuff) origin/old_branch into local's other_branch)

Answer (score 0):

`git branch -f` destroys the upstream branch info etc.
Typing a `git update-ref` command, which principally operates cleanly, is tedious and error-prone. It could create any kind of nonsense file under `.git`.

As this operation is needed frequently, do it via a rather safe alias or script:

```
git reset-other OTHERBRANCHNAME TARGETREF
```

After adding e.g. this alias to your config:

```
[alias]
    reset-other = "!f() { git show -s refs/heads/$1 -- && git update-ref refs/heads/$1 $2 && git show -s $1; }; f"
```

Add from command-line:

```
git config --global alias.reset-other "!f() { git show -s refs/heads/$1 -- && git update-ref refs/heads/$1 $2 && git show -s $1; }; f"
```

When the move succeeded to a wrong target by a slip you already have the SHA printed on the screen to move back ...