# Remove an older git commit that has already been pushed to remote

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to remove a git commit that has already been merged in the master branch on bitbucket a while back. In this example I want to remove the commit highlighted in yellow in the image below.

[image]

Any help with this please?

Comment: What do you mean remove it? Do you mean to undo the changes that the commit introduces or complete remove it from your git history? Are you ready to re-write the projects git history in order to do so and will others be affected by this (aka are you working alone on this project)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938301/remove-specific-commit) or [Delete commits from a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of solving the problem.
One will **safely** undo the changes of the commit, and the other will totally remove the commit from the history. Below you can find the details.

### Solution 1: Revert the commit and push to remote

This will create a **new** commit that reverts the changes which were done in that older commit.
To do it you'll just need to run the following command:
`git revert <COMMIT_ID>`
If there are merge conflicts, resolve it and afterwards push your new commit to remote as usual.

**Note:** Since this is a new commit, your original commit will stay in the remote, and the new commit will be added to the top. So, the code will be reverted, but the old commit will stay there.

### Solution 2. Interactively rebase and force push to remote

This will totally **remove** the commit from the log, but might be [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55053152/risk-of-using-git-interactive-rebase-to-only-change-author-name-in-a-set-of-comm) if you're working on a team and the other team-members already are doing changes on the same parts.

Let's say you have 5 commits in a branch:
`commit1 -> commit2 -> commit3 -> commit4 -> commit5 (HEAD)`
you're on the 5th commit (head) and you want to remove the second commit there.

To do so, you'll have to run the following command:
`git rebase -i HEAD~4`
where `-i` is the command for interactive-rebase, and `HEAD~4` means rebase the last 4 commits.

After running the command, an editor will be opened with a text like this:

```
pick d8389ew My Last Commit
pick f7f3f6d Another commit that is okay to keep
pick 310154e A commit that is okay to keep
pick a5f4a0d The commit that I want to remove
```

There you can see that the commit on the bottom is the one that you want to drop.
You'll need to replace the word `pick` with `drop`

```
pick d8389ew My Last Commit
pick f7f3f6d Another commit that is okay to keep
pick 310154e A commit that is okay to keep
drop a5f4a0d The commit that I want to remove
```

Now you can save the file, close the editor and rebase will be done.
There might be some merge conflicts again. If there are, then just resolve them (and do `git rebase --continue` if needed to finish it).

After doing the rebase your branch will now look like this (commit2 is removed):
`commit1 -> commit3 -> commit4 -> commit5 (HEAD)`

So now all you have to do is to force push your branch to the remote.

But **WARNING**: if you are doing it on a branch on which other guys are working (e.g. master, main), make sure that all they are aware of the changes, otherwise you might break the things.

To push the branch just use the `--force` command in the end:
`git push origin my-branch-name --force`
And afterwards don't forget to let the team-members know to fetch the latest updates on their side.

**Notes**:

- For more info on interactive rebase see [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)
- This approach will actually drop the last 4 commits and create newer ones with the same changes (will rewrite the history). This will break the refs for the other guys if they were working on the same branch. To fix the issues on their side see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55053152/risk-of-using-git-interactive-rebase-to-only-change-author-name-in-a-set-of-comm). But if the branch is only used by you then you're fine.

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that the reason for the danger is that the new branch will consist of commits which _look like_ commit3, commit4 and commit5 _but are actually new commits, with new hashes_.