# How can I reset another branch to the origin without checking it out?

Tags: git

A typical workflow I have is to checkout `master` and type `git reset --hard @{u}`.
From there I will checkout the branch I want to merge master with and merge `master`.

Can I perform the steps of updating `master` without changing to it? (This would help me not stash when changing)

For example, I am on branch `A` which was branched from `master`. `master` has been worked on and I have a lot of changes and don't want to perform a stash, so instead of performing a

1. `git stash`
2. `git checkout master`
3. `git reset --hard @{u}`
4. `git checkout A`
5. `git merge master`
6. `git pop stash (pseudo)`

I want to be able to perform a `git reset --hard @{u}` for `master` while currently on branch `A`,

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591107/reset-other-branch-to-current-without-a-checkout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset other branch to current without a checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591107/reset-other-branch-to-current-without-a-checkout)

Comment: I don't think those answers involve performing a hard reset on it.

Comment: Just use `git merge origin/master`? There's no need to checkout or bump around your local `master` branch just to merge what is on `origin/master` into your branch. You can just merge `origin/master` directly, and it's identical with 1/3th the steps.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I perform the steps of updating master without changing to it?

Yes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17604903/9305398).

> I don't think those answers involve performing a hard reset on it.

A hard reset does not make sense when you are not checking out the other branch.

If you weren't doing a merge, you could also avoid the `stash` by using a soft reset rather than a mixed one, too.

So (almost) all your steps condense to a single `branch` or soft `reset` command as explained in that answer.

---

In general, your workflow seems strange. To update `master` to be in sync with upstream, you would normally fast-forward `merge` the changes. But there is no need to do so, you can base your work branch on top of a remote branch after a `fetch`.

Furthermore, you would normally either merge `master` into your local branch to keep them in sync, or `rebase` your branch on top of `master`; depending on your style of workflow (whether you want history to be more linear or not).

Using `stash`, in general, should be a rare thing to do.

Comment: The answer to that question seems to be updating `master` to match `A`, not, resetting `master` to be updated to the upstream state and then updating `A` with `master`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are trying to update the other branch to, you can point it to an arbitrary commit as needed. Of course, merging it is its own step (edited answer to clarify).

Comment: Edited again to put some more tips, since the workflow you are using sounds like it could be improved greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git worktree`.

```
git worktree add /path/to/foo master
cd /path/to/foo
git reset --hard @{u}
# remove the working tree when it's not needed any more
git worktree remove /path/to/foo
```

It checks out `master` in another working tree and does not affect the current working tree where `A` has been checked out.

But, why would you insist on using `git reset --hard`? `git update-ref` is indeed a better solution.

Comment: I have not used `git update-ref` before I just find `git fetch` into `git reset --hard @{u}` a reliable way of saying "Hard reset this to upstream"